# Removing all non-unique members of a list

Tags: java, loops, exception, concurrentmodification

I wanted to create a method that would filter out all non-unique members of a list, such that a list with an input

> 3 5 3 8 8 2

Would become

> 5 2

I had the idea to try the following:

```
private static List<Integer> getUniques(List<Integer> list) {
        for (Integer n : list) {
            list.remove(n);
            if (!list.contains(n)) {
                list.add(n);
            } else {
                while (list.contains(n)) {
                    list.remove(n);
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But this throws a Concurrent Modification exception. I made a working adjustment:

```
private static List<Integer> getUniques(List<Integer> list) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Integer> distinctSet = new HashSet<>();

        distinctSet.addAll(list);
        result.addAll(list);

        for (Integer n : distinctSet) {
            result.remove(n);
            if (!result.contains(n)) {
                result.add(n);
            } else {
                while (result.contains(n)) {
                    result.remove(n);
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This accomplishes what I want, but seems a bit convoluted/inefficient.  Is there a way for me to do it the first way I had in mind? Or another more efficient method in general? Or am I already essentially using the best approach available?

Comment: Use Iterator to traverse the list and then use iterator's remove method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove() to remove the elements from list
ex: http://www.java-examples.com/remove-element-collection-using-java-iterator-example

Comment: Iterator doesn't have an add method so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better approach is to use a `HashMap` to flag elements to keep, then add based on that. This approach is `O(N)`, which is better than the `O(N^2)` of your solution (remove may be `O(N)`, depending on the List implementation passed in). It also certainly preserves the ordering of the elements in the original list, if that is important.

```
private static List<Integer> getUniques(List<Integer> list) {
    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> flagMap = new HashMap<>();

    //Total Loop: O(N)
    for(Integer i : list){
        if(flagMap.containsKey(i)) flagMap.put(i, false); //O(1)
        else flagMap.put(i, true); //O(1)
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //Total Loop: O(N)
    for(Integer i : list){
        if(flagMap.get(i)) result.add(i); //O(1)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with a method to count the number of times an item appears in a `List`. Something like

```
private static <T> int count(List<T> al, T val) {
    int r = 0;
    for (T t : al) {
        if (t.equals(val)) {
            r++;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Then create a new `List` to return, and check the `count` is 1 before you add it to that `List` like

```
private static List<Integer> getUniques(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer n : list) {
        if (count(list, n) == 1) {
            al.add(n);
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8, you can do what Mshnik is doing using the stream API. However, as this is still a new API, you may want to use this with a bit of caution at work. Readability (by you as well as your peers) should triumph over conciseness. If using Java 8/stream API is not an option then Mshnik's solution is what I'd go with.

```
List<Integer> uniques = 
    list.stream().
         collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.reducing(0, (a, b) -> a + b))). //Adding all occurances of that number {3->6, 5->5, 8->16, 2->2}
         entrySet().stream(). //The above map's entries as a set
         filter(e -> e.getValue() == e.getKey()). //Retains {5->5, 2->2}
         map(e -> e.getKey()). //Retains {5, 2}
         collect(Collectors.<Integer>toList()); //Collects
```

Note that while each line may seem as another iteration over the list, this is actually a 2-pass solution (first pass is when we collect as map and the second pass when we collect the list).

Complexity: *expected* O(N) --as the groupingBy would use a HashMap.